# python dataframe to postgresql

Tags: python, database, postgresql, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I imported a table from sql server database as a dataframe, I am trying to export it as PostgreSQL table

[this is what I am doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQkmi.png)

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:000000@localhost:5432/sinistrePY')
df.to_sql('table_name3', engine)
```

[and this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GotPU.png)

the data integration is working fine but

1. I get the table with read-only privileges
2. data types are not as I should be
3. no primary key
4. I don't need the index column

how can I fix that and control how I want my table to be, from my notebook or directly from PostgreSQL server if needed, thanks.

Comment: to skip index, pass `index=False`, specify `dtype` for column types.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what iI needed , also about that ready only constraint it's because no primary key determined .